# how to make the geojson format with lineString

Tags: java, json, geojson, spring-jdbc

Excuse me but I have a question, I do not know what pojos would have to create to give
format to a geojson type lineString with its points

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "LineString"
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  -87.72158863628451,
                  41.88857748226596
                ],
                [
                  -87.71467926585602,
                  41.88753117344939
                ]
              ],
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.415061, 40.506229]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.505184, 40.488084]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.354465, 40.488737]
            }
        }]
    }
```

from what I see when I put the coordinates I see it very difficult because the coordinates object must carry the same name Line String and Point.
With the chicken that I have below with this I use to obtain the point type coordinates, I would like to know what I would have to do without having to overload the pojos

```
    private String type;

List<Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public List<Double> getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question in the Spanish Stack Overflow http://es.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: sorry, but I have the question in english . 
I've already corrected my mistake